# Redirect SWI-Prolog console output to a file

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I'm trying to write output from `make_tests` to a file, but nothing I've tried seems to insert the correct information in the output file.

I've looked at SWI documentaion at http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/SWI-Prolog/Manual/IO.html and have tried a whole bunch of those predicates but none have worked.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
:- use_module(library(test_wizard)).

init_test_file(FILE) :-
   set_prolog_flag(log_query_file, FILE).

gen_test_in(FILE) :-
   make_tests(lists, FILE, current_output).
```

So running this (in console) for example:

```
init_test_file('mytest.pro').
member(a, [a,b]).
gen_test_in('mytest.pro').
```

I get the following output (in console):

```
true.

6 ?- gen_test_in('r.pro').
:- begin_tests(lists).

test(member, [nondet]) :-
        member(a, [a, b]).

:- end_tests(lists).
true.
```

How do I get this same output (starting at `begin_tests` and ending at `end_tests` in a text file?

I tried doing things like modifying `gen_test_in` to:

```
gen_test_in(FILE) :-
   open(FILE, write, Out),
   make_tests(lists, FILE, Out),
   close(Out).
```

But I just get an empty text file.

Comment: The goal `Close(Out)` in the body of `gen_test_in/1` can't possibly be right, or can it?

Comment: @repeat It took me another 1/2 minute staring at this to notice the capital letter there.

Comment: Sorry didn't intend for it to be capital. I've edited it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are messing up the arguments here. The library you are using, `library(test_wizard)`, is meant for generating tests from queries. In the predicate you are using, `make_tests/3`, you have the following three arguments:

1. The module
2. The file ***from** which the queries are **read***
3. The stream ***to** which the generated tests are **written***

In the examples you use, you either set your output stream to be `current_output` (so standard output if you are on the top level), or, in the last example you give, you are opening the file you want to read for *writing*, and then pass the file and its handle to `make_tests/3`. Instead, if you have a file called `queries.pl`:

```
$ cat queries.pl
member(a, [a,b]).
member(X, [a,b]).
```

Then:

```
$ swipl
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 7.3.16-36-g42820df)
Copyright (c) 1990-2015 University of Amsterdam, VU Amsterdam
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Please visit http://www.swi-prolog.org for details.

For help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- use_module(library(test_wizard)).
true.

?- setup_call_cleanup(open('lists.plt', write, Out),
                      make_tests(lists, 'queries.pl', Out),
                      close(Out)).
Out = <stream>(0xe59ef0).

?- halt.
$ cat lists.plt 
:- begin_tests(lists).

test(member, [nondet]) :-
    member(a, [a, b]).
test(member, [all(A==[a, b])]) :-
    member(A, [a, b]).

:- end_tests(lists).
```

Comment: Thanks Boris. That worked for me. So essentially, the way I see it, the output stream cannot belong to a file that is also the input file for queries.

Comment: @Ash You could try opening the same file in `append` mode instead of `write` mode, to see what happens (it "worked" for me), but I don't think this is a very good idea. You would need an explicit guarantee by `make_tests/3` that it first reads all the queries, and only queries, and then appends to the same file.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I don't think it's a good idea either. Just curious :)